# FOSRestbundle, JMS Serializer and SonataMediaBundle return public url for image

Tags: jms, symfony-sonata, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to return a JSON object('Module') with a ManyToOne link to an Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity through FOSRestBundle and JMS Serializer. How should I go about doing that?

Here's a hack that I did, but dont think it's the best practise.

```
class Module
{
    ...
    /**
     * @var Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media",  inversedBy="module")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hero_image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    private $heroImage;
    ...
}

class Media extends BaseMedia
{
   ...
   /**
     * A Quick hack not the best method.
     *
     * @JMS\VirtualProperty
     * @JMS\SerializedName("url")
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrlMethod()
    {
        global $kernel;

        $imageProvider = $kernel->getContainer()->get('sonata.media.provider.image');

        return $imageProvider->generatePublicUrl($this, 'reference');
    }
    ...
}
```

thank you!

**EDIT**
Thanks to Tautrimas Pajarskas and the post he mention.
Here's the class.

```
<?php
namespace AXO\APIBundle\Listener\Serialization;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Tag;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;

/**
 * Add data after serialization
 *
 * @Service("axo.listener.serializationlistener")
 * @Tag("jms_serializer.event_subscriber")
 */
class SerializationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.post_serialize', 'class' => 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media', 'method' => 'onPostSerialize'),
        );
    }

    public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        global $kernel;
        $imageProvider = $kernel->getContainer()->get('sonata.media.provider.image');

        $event->getVisitor()->addData('url',$imageProvider->generatePublicUrl($event->getObject(), 'reference'));
    }
}
```

Comment: And in services.yml you would register the service that way:
`services:
    AXO.listener.serializationlistener:
        class: AXO\APIBundle\Listener\Serialization\SerializationListener
        tags:
            - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber, event: serializer.post_serialize, method: onPostSerialize }`

Comment: why not get the provider for $event->getObject()->getProviderName() rather than hardcoded for the image provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to see [Add extra fields using JMS Serializer bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007281/add-extra-fields-using-jms-serializer-bundle) as it has an example, on how to add additional fields to serialized data that depend on external classes.