# Symfony and JMSSerialier, can't add listener to add extra fields

Tags: php, json, symfony, jms-serializer

I tried to follow this answer:
[Add extra fields using JMS Serializer bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007281/add-extra-fields-using-jms-serializer-bundle)

but no change..

I want to add extra fields to a serialized entity (in json) before sending it. Is there something that I missed ?

Here is my Listener:

```
<?php

namespace My\MyBundle\Listener;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Service;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Tag;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\Inject;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation\InjectParams;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\PostResponseEvent;
use My\MyBundle\Entity\Dossier;
use JMS\Serializer\Handler\SubscribingHandlerInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\PreSerializeEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use JMS\Serializer\GraphNavigator;
use JMS\Serializer\JsonSerializationVisitor;

/**
 * Add data after serialization
 *
 * @Service("my.listener.serializationlistener")
 * @Tag("jms_serializer.event_subscriber")
 */
class SerializationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array('event' => 'serializer.post_serialize', 'class' => 'My\MyBundle\Entity\Dossier', 'method' => 'onPostSerialize'),
        );
    }

    public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
        $event->getVisitor()->addData('someKey','someValue');
    }
}
```

and the call in my controller:

```
$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
$res = $serializer->serialize($dossier, 'json');
```

I also add the following service declaration:

```
services:
    my.mybundle.listener:
        class: My\MyBundle\Listener\SerializationListener
```

I have another service declared and when I change its declaration name symfony give and error, not when I do it with the listener service.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your actual code ?

Comment: I just added the code

Comment: @Mehdi did you manage to serialze an object as the extra field (instead of the string 'someValue')? Please see my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441456/jms-virtualproperty-with-argument-and-custom-listener-subscriber

Answer (score 2):

```
$visitor = $event->getVisitor();
$visitor->visitProperty(new StaticPropertyMetadata('', 'some_key', null),'some_key');
```

The `addData` method is for old version of JMS Serializer. Don't forget to import `StaticPropertyMetadata`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you forgot to add a tag. Your listener declaration should looks something like this

```
services:
    my.bundle.listener:
        class: My\MyBundle\Listener\SerializationListener
        tags:
            -  { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Just in case.. I've just added a new event in my listener (post_serialize). I already have pre_serialize and nothing happens for post event.. Clearing the cache did the trick..